# Completable future problem with terminating ExecutorService

Tags: java, completable-future

Doing some basic web scraper.

I want run scraping in parallel with multiple threads using Completable future. Each job retrieves Page object which needs to scrape and returns Page object with list of founded urls.

Each url from list starts new job if it's not already submitted for scraping. After all parallel jobs are done I want to proceed with logic.

Problem with this code that only scrape first page object and then it terminates, if I remove "allFutures.thenRun(() -> executorService.shutdown());" then it collects all pages/urls but program never ends.

```
public class Demo
{
    private final Set<Page> pages = new HashSet<>();
    private final Set<Page> submittedPages = new HashSet<>();

    private final ExecutorService executorService;

    public Demo(final int numberOfThreads)
    {
        this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    }

    public void start(String url) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException
    {
        this.submitTask(new Page(url));
        CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[completableFutureList.size()]));
        allFutures.thenRun(() -> executorService.shutdown());

        // do something with pages
    }


    private void submitTask(final Page page)
    {
        if (!this.submittedPages.contains(page))
        {
            this.submittedPages.add(page);
            CompletableFuture<Void> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new Task(page).call(), this.executorService) //want to run this parallel in multiple threads
               .thenAccept(receivedPage -> {
                   this.savePage(receivedPage);
                   this.submitCollectedLinks(receivedPage);
               });
            completableFutureList.add(cf);

        }
    }

    private void submitCollectedLinks(final Page page){
        page.getLinks()
          .stream()
          .map(Page::new)
          .forEach(this::submitTask);
    }

    private void savePage(final Page page)
    {
        this.pages.add(page);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `start` method adds one task, submits it to be run, collects the future through `allOf` and when the tasks finishes shuts down the executor.

Comment: Wait until you've submitted all your tasks before collecting them and chaining the `thenRun`.

Comment: Hmm how I could find out when last task is submitted, or there is no new task

Comment: Then you'll have to rethink your design. Maybe accept a list of tasks. Or provide a `shutdown` method of your own that the caller can invoke.

Comment: Problem is that I start only one task (e.g scrap index page), result of first task creates another tasks (scrap founded pages on index page: e.g page2, page3, page4), those new tasks again creates new tasks (scrap subpages of page2, page 3, page 4) and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. You are scheduling the shutdown of the executor service on the completion of a snapshot of the `completableFutureList` when there could be more futures added later-on, but even worse, you reach the point `// do something with pages` when not even the snapshot has been completed yet.

You didn’t show the declaration of `completableFutureList`, but given that `pages` and `submittedPages`, which you modify from different threads, are initialized with `HashSet`, which is not thread safe, I have no good feeling about the list either. But you don’t need the list anyway. You should change the submitting code to return futures representing the pending tasks being *composed* with the subsequent tasks. The function passed to `thenCompose` will get evaluated when the prerequisite stage has been completed, in other words, this allows dependencies to futures not known when chaining the function.

Note that replacing the `HashSet`s with thread safe constructs is not enough. You have to avoid sequences like calling `contains` before `add`, as there is no guaranty that no other thread will perform `add` between these two calls (known as “check-then-act” anti-pattern). You can use just `add`, which will already do nothing and return `false` when the element is already present. Using the right thread safe `Set` implementation, it provides the required atomicity.

Putting these things together, you’ll get, e.g.

```
public class Demo {
    private final Set<Page> pages = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    private final Set<Page> submittedPages = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    private final ExecutorService executorService;

    public Demo(final int numberOfThreads) {
        this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    }

    public void start(String url) {
        this.submitTask(new Page(url))
            // shutdown even in the exceptional case
            .whenComplete((_void, throwable) -> executorService.shutdown())
            .join(); // wait for completion before doing something with pages

        // do something with pages
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Void> submitTask(final Page page) {
        // use a single add to avoid check-then-act anti-pattern
        if(this.submittedPages.add(page)) {
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Task(page)::call, executorService)
                // compose with recursively encountered tasks
               .thenCompose(receivedPage -> {
                   this.savePage(receivedPage);
                   return this.submitCollectedLinks(receivedPage);
               });
        }

        // do nothing when already submitted
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Void> submitCollectedLinks(final Page page) {
        return CompletableFuture.allOf(page.getLinks()
          .stream().map(Page::new).map(this::submitTask)
          .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new));
    }

    private void savePage(final Page page) {
        this.pages.add(page);
    }
}
```